Overlapping Autofilled Values in Ant Design Input Wrapper with Customized Floating Labels
I've customized the Ant Design Input component to include floating labels in my project. This wrapper is used in a login form for both email and password fields. However, I'm encountering an issue when the browser autofills the login credentials, particularly when the password is autofilled. The autofilled value overlaps with my floating label.
  errorStyle: {
    lineHeight: variables.lineHeightSmall,
    fontSize: variables.fontSizeSmall,
    color: variables.error,
    marginTop: variables._0_5Rem,
  },
  labelStyle: {
    color: variables.inputLabel,
    lineHeight: variables.lineHeightSmall,
    fontSize: variables.fontSizeNormal,
    transition: 'all 0.3s ease',
    transform: 'translateY(-50%)',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: variables._50Percentage,
    padding: `0 0 0 ${variables._0_875Rem}`,
  },
  inputStyle: (size, error) => ({
    backgroundColor: variables.primaryBg,
    padding: variables._1Rem,
    fontSize: variables.fontSizeNormal,
    borderRadius: variables._0_125Rem,
    zIndex: 0,
    border: error ? variables.errorLight : variables.inputBorder,
    transition: 'all 0.3s ease',
    ...(size === 'small' && { height: variables.mediumHeight }),
    ':focus': {
      border: `${variables._0_063Rem} solid ${variables.primaryColor}`,
    },
  }),
  requiredStyle: {
    color: variables.error,
    paddingLeft: variables._0_125Rem,
  },
  inputFocusStyle: {
    transform: `translate(${variables._0_75Rem},-${variables._190Percentage})`,
    background: variables.primaryBg,
    padding: `0 ${variables._0_875Rem}`,
  },
  showTextStyle: {
    color: variables.textPrimary,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    borderBottom: `1px solid ${variables.textPrimary}`,
  },
};

export default function InputComponent({
  threeRowStyle,
  style,
  value,
  onChange,
  className,
  placeholder,
  label,
  labelProps,
  isPassword,
  required,
  error,
  size,
  autoComplete,
  suffix,
  middleSectionStyle,
  labelStyle,
  type = 'text',
  ...props
}) {
  let Component = Input;
  if (isPassword) {
    Component = Input.Password;
  }
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const inputRef = useRef();

  const handleFocus = (e) => {
    setFocused(true);
  };

  const handleBlur = () => {
    setFocused(false);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setVisible(true);
  };

  const renderPasswordToggle = (visible) => {
    return (
      <span style={customInputStyle.showTextStyle} onClick={handleClick}>
        {visible ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}
      </span>
    );
  };

  return (
        <>
          <Component
            {...(isPassword && { iconRender: renderPasswordToggle })}
            ref={inputRef}
            value={value}
            style={{
              ...customInputStyle.inputStyle(size, error),
              ...style,
              ...(error
                ? {
                    border: variables.inputErrorBorder,
                  }
                : {}),
              ...(focused && !error
                ? { border: variables.inputFocusedBorder }
                : {}),
            }}
            onChange={onChange}
            className={className}
            autoComplete={autoComplete || 'off'}
            type={isPassword ? (visible ? 'text' : 'password') : type}
            onFocus={handleFocus}
            onBlurCapture={handleBlur}
            {...props}
          />
          <TextComponent
            style={{
              ...customInputStyle.labelStyle,
              ...(focused || value ? customInputStyle.inputFocusStyle : {}),
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              inputRef.current.focus();
            }}
          >
            {label}
            {required && <span style={customInputStyle.requiredStyle}>*</span>}
          </TextComponent>
        </>
  );
}


I have tried various solutions like setting id of password field to new-password but that does not work and try to turn on autocomplete
